# There exists a composite number $n$ such that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < \lambda.$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, convergence-divergence

If $\lambda > 1$, then there exists a composite number $n$ such that $$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < \lambda.$$

I am able to show that $\displaystyle \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \sum_{d|n}  \frac{1}{d}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$.

But I can't proceed further. Can someone give some hints?

Comment: Certainly, that sum is very short if $n$ is a prime.

Comment: @EricTowers but we have to choose composite numbers.

Comment: So how short can you make that sum?  (You only asked for a hint.)

Comment: Try $n = p^2$ where $p$ is prime and take $p \rightarrow \infty$